# Computing differential of a $0$-form

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, differential-forms, differential, multilinear-algebra

I am stuck on problem 30.1 from Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds.
The question is to directly compute that $d(d\omega)=0$, given that $\omega = xy dx + 3 dy - yz dz$. So far I found that this $\omega$ we're dealing with is a 0-form, so theorem 30.3 in Munkres gives us that $d\omega$ would be defined by $(D_{1}f dx_{1}+D_{2}f dx_{2}+D_{3}f dx_{3})$. But I don't really understand how to use this theorem. What would be our $f$ in this case? And do we use $dx, dy, dz$ as $dx_1,dx_2,dx_3$, respectively?
While not really understanding what $f$ stands for in this formula, I have computed the following now:
$d\omega = D_{1}f dx+D_{2}f dy+D_{3}f dz=xdx-ydz$, but this does not seem to get me anywhere.

Comment: $\omega$ is a $1$-form, not a $0$-form.

Comment: How do we see that? It just maps to $\mathbb{R}$ right?

Comment: It is a sum of terms, each of which is a multiple of a 1-form (`dx` or `dy` or `dz`). A 0-form is just a function.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlo2V8H5khM

Comment: Every $k$-form over $\mathbb R$ “just maps to $\mathbb R$.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, $\omega$ is a one-form. The general formula for the exterior derivative of a one-form $\omega=\sum_i f_i\ dx^i$ is $$d\omega=\sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x^j}dx^j\wedge dx^i.$$ If we compute that for the given $\omega$, we get $$d\omega=y\ dx\wedge dx+x\ dy\wedge dx+0-z\ dy\wedge dz-y\ dz\wedge dz=-x\ dx\wedge dy -z\ dy\wedge dz.$$ Similarly, if we compute $d(d\omega),$ we get $$d(d\omega)=-dx\wedge dx\wedge dy-dz\wedge dy\wedge dz=0.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This makes it more clear to me. The definition of the exterior derivative of a 1-form in Munkres is given as follows: $d\omega = \sum_{[I]} df_{I}dx_{I}$. Could we somehow relate this to your definition?

Comment: Also, I do not understand how we can compute $d(d\omega)$ now. $d\omega$ has wedge products in it, how can we see this as the right input to put into the operator $d$ again?

Comment: To answer your first question, they're the same definition if you write out the multi-indices ($I$ in Munkres' definition is a multi-index). The way Munkres wrote it is more compact and is more directly applicable to forms of arbitrary degree, but I wrote out a more expanded definition for one-forms to ensure that I didn't obscure anything.

Comment: To answer your second one, I technically didn't write down a definition telling you how to take the exterior derivative of a $2$-form, but I was hoping that you could extrapolate from the pattern that you should see in computing $d\omega$. Alternatively, you can use Munkres' definition. The pattern is to take partial derivatives of the coefficient functions and add in a $d$ of whichever partial you took to the front of your wedge.

Comment: Thank you. I think I still need to take some time studying this, it is all still a bit abracadabra to me. So in computing $d(d\omega)$, I think what I don't understand is what we would see as the coefficient functions since they are now mixed with wedge products as well. Would the $f_{i}$'s be $-x $ and $-z$?

Comment: Yup, the coefficients will be whatever functions are in front of the wedges!

Comment: Okay, thank you! Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: No problem! $\ $